# Google calendar api event feed not giving "where"

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, zend-gdata

I am using the zend google api library to retrieve a list of event from a public calendar. I am successfully able to retrieve the `title`, `when`, and `content`, but `where` is an empty array. Any documentation that I have found in the past 3 hours from Google, Zend or otherwise is terrible and does not give a list of possible values. The only documentation I can find on the location of the event is how to set it if you are creating an event.

How do I access the location?

```
<?php
            foreach ($eventFeed as $event) :
                ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="event_title">
                        <?php echo $event->title->text;?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="event_time">
                        <?php echo date('h:ia', strtotime($event->when[0]->startTime));?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="event_location">
                        <?php echo $event->where?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="event_description">
                        <?php echo $event->content->text?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$where=$event->Where;
    foreach($where as $eventplace)
    {
        echo $eventplace;
    }
```

It will give you location.

The main reason is that it gives the location value in array so we have to find it out manually....